# How to improve SQL query speed on Date in a larger Database

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

I am trying to optimize an SQL query to increase the speed of its execution. I already found out that the Date column is the problem. When I run this query including the date in the Database:

```
SELECT p.*, preis.preis
FROM produkt p INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM preis WHERE DATE(preis.Datum) = CURDATE()) preis ON p.id = preis.produkt_id
WHERE artikel_id IN (SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1)
```

it needs 28 seconds to get a result. But when I change the WHERE-Clause of the INNER JOIN select to `id > 256981` where I get the same result, it just need 0,062 seconds.

```
SELECT p.*, preis.preis
FROM produkt p INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM preis WHERE preis.id > 256981) preis ON p.id = preis.produkt_id
WHERE artikel_id IN (SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1)
```

This is a big difference.

I already read something about INDEX and the different INDEX-types, but I cant find a solution to INDEX a DATE field in the correct way.
Or are there other ways to improve queries like this?

Comment: So what is the problem of creating an index on the date column?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I added a normal index to the date field but it dont affect the query time and still needs about 28 seconds. So I  asked me if I need a special one for date columns

Comment: Create a today date before query then use it like WHERE preis.Datum = '2021-01-20'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.*, q.preis
    FROM  ( SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1 ) AS a
    JOIN produkt p USING(artikel_id)
    INNER JOIN  
        ( SELECT  preis
            FROM  preis
            WHERE  Datum >= CURDATE()
               AND Datum  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ) AS q  ON p.id = q.produkt_id
```

And have these indexes:

```
preis:  INDEX(Datum, produkt_id, preis)
preis:  INDEX(produkt_id, Datum, preis)
produkt:  INDEX(haendler_id, artikel_id)
produkt:  INDEX(artikel_id)
```

If there can be only one `preis` for produkt, then there is another alternative.

We really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- to check datatypes, PRIMARY KEY, and other things.

Comment: Thank you! Your query  prints the right data in 1 sec. But I dont really understand why..

Comment: @Peacycode - Some of what I did...  I rearranged the 3 tables, trying to think how I might tackle the problem manually:  first was to get the one artikel_id; last was to check the preis.  The order help me understand the query; the Optimizer will rearrange the tables if it chooses.  As for indexes, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using join without sub-query and condition directly on `datum` without date function as follows:

```
SELECT p.*, preis.preis
  FROM produkt p 
 INNER JOIN preis ON p.id = preis.produkt_id
WHERE preis.Datum >= CURDATE() and preis.Datum < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND artikel_id IN (SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1)
```

You can create the index on `preis.Datum` as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX preis_indx_01 ON preis(Datum);
```

**Note**: You can also consider creating the index on `produkt_id` if it is used in the joins frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The query also needs the 28 sec when your query. I created the index like you but it also didn't affect the query. If the produkt_id is a foreign key isn't already indexed?

Comment: Create the index as I have created in the answer and execute the query from the answer. not the query from question. Foriegn keys are not indexed. You have to create index on it.

Comment: I have indexed the date and the foreign key now, but when i hit your query nothing changed.

Comment: You should see the explain plan then.

Comment: @Peacycode - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what is indexed and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is when you use mysql any build function like **CURDATE()**  which make query slow so try to avoid it if possible so try to update your query like this

```
// first make today date if your code is php then $today = date('Y-m-d');
then use this in mysql 
SELECT p.*, preis.preis
FROM produkt p INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM preis WHERE DATE(preis.Datum) = '$today') 
preis ON p.id = preis.produkt_id
WHERE artikel_id IN (SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1)
```

Better if you avoid also **DATE**

```
SELECT p.*, preis.preis
FROM produkt p INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM preis WHERE preis.Datum = '$today') 
preis ON p.id = preis.produkt_id
WHERE artikel_id IN (SELECT artikel_id FROM produkt WHERE haendler_id = 1)
```

I think this will help you

Comment: I tried the first query and it improved the time about a few seconds, but still over 20sec. The second query dont give me a column back.

Comment: May be your Datum is datetime column so need DATE function so 2nd not work

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam - `CURDATE()`, like `NOW()`, is effectively a constant when it comes to optimization.  `DATE(column)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use subquery.  Second, I don't recommend `in` either.  So:

```
SELECT p.*, pp.preis
FROM produkt p INNER JOIN
     preis pp
     ON p.id = pp.produkt_id
WHERE p.Datum >= CURDATE() AND
      p.Datum < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM produkt p2
              WHERE p2.artikel_id = p.artikel_id AND
                    p2.haendler_id = 1
             );
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on `product(artikel_id, haendler_id)` and `preis(Datum, product_id)`.

Comment: Your answer improved the query time about 10 seconds. I now found out that the fetching time is about 18 seconds.

Comment: @Peacycode . .  It must be retrieving a lot of data, then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an index on your `id` column, but don't have an index on the data column, define an index on that column and you should get almost same result.